# my code is adding every object related to that user into a model with many to many relationship

Tags: python, django

So I'm trying to add specfic items/objects which the user asked for but instead it is adding every item related to that user, for example order 1 is `Item 1 and Item 2` then if second order is placed then it will add `item 3, item4, item1 and item 2` while `item 1 and item 2` were not requested by the user. My code is like this:

```
specificItems = []
for item in data:
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=itemId)
    user = UserLogin.objects.get(token=userToken).user
    specificItems.append(OrderItem.objects.create(user=user, product=product)) 
userObject = UserLogin.objects.get(token=finalUserToken).user
FinalOrder = Order.objects.create(user=userObject, order_id=another_token)
FinalOrder.products.add(*specificItems)
FinalOrder.save()
```

Also I have a many to many relationship with `Order` to `OrderItems`

data is a set of objects (product) given by the user that is requesting those products to be ordered, The objects are in a list. Here is an example:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Product 1","price":20},{"id":2,"name":"Product 2","price":5}]
```

Comment: What is `data`? Please make sure the code you show is a _[mre]_ before posting it.

Comment: I have edited my question! Thanks for your interest in helping me